# Cambiar imagen usando mouseover

Tags: javascript

Mi objetivo es que al pasar el mouse por encima de la imagen, esta cambie a otra.

## HTML

```
<body>
 <img src="ikefeliz_2.png" id="imagen">
</body>
```

## Js

```
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar(){
  var imagen=document.getElementById('imagen');
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', peligro, false);
}

function peligro(){
  var imagen=document.getElementById('imagen').innerHTML="ikepeligro_2.png";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Codigo

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {
  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', peligro, false);
}

function peligro() {
  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen').src = "https://img.utdstc.com/icons/256/app-danger-check-android.png";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="http://requirementsinc.com/img/icon/PNG/danger.png" id="imagen">
</body>
```

---

### Explicacion

El problema es que estas haciendo esto:

```
var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen').innerHTML = "https://img.utdstc.com/icons/256/app-danger-check-android.png";
```

Cuando en su lugar deberias hacer esto:

```
var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen').src = "https://img.utdstc.com/icons/256/app-danger-check-android.png";
```

Lo que ocurre cuando cambias el atributo `.innerHTML` es que cambias lo que se encuentre dentro de tu elemento imagen, es decir, lo que se encuentre después del `>` hasta el `<`, mientras que al cambiar el atributo `src`, modificas realmente el origen de la imagen de la etiqueta.

---

### Actualizacion

He dejado un ejemplo que podría servirte si quieres que al alejar el mouse se restaure la imagen original.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {
  
  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
  
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', peligro, false);
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseout', restaurar, false);
}

function restaurar(){
  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen').src = "http://requirementsinc.com/img/icon/PNG/danger.png";
}

function peligro() {
  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen').src = "https://img.utdstc.com/icons/256/app-danger-check-android.png";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="http://requirementsinc.com/img/icon/PNG/danger.png" id="imagen">
</body>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda  :)

Comment: @Vendetta Con mucho gusto, si la respuesta te ha servido, no olvides marcarla como aceptada, asi contribuimos a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema.

Comment: @Vendetta Por cierto, he agregado un ejemplo ma que podria servirte por si quieres restaurar la imagen original cuando el mouse este por fuera

Comment: Lo vi, tenia pensado usar también el mouseout, pero me iba a dar el mismo problema así que simplifique código. Igualmente muchísimas gracias por las molestias. PD: Tenia que pasar unos minutos para aceptarte la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes cambiar la imagen con el evento definido en el mismo HTML así:

```
<img src="ikefeliz_2.png" onmouseover="this.src='ikepeligro_2.jpg'">
```

Comment: Además de *onmouseover* se aconseja poner *onmouseout* para que la imagen no se quede siempre cambiada.

Answer (score 2):

solo quiero complementar la respuesta de @ivan-botero usando funciones anónimas y haciendo referencias en el scope adecuado para evitar el pequeño overhead de las funciones nombradas, la asignación de una variable `imagen` en cada evento y la búsqueda del elemento en el DOM en cada evento también:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {      
  var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen'), original = imagen.src;
  
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      this.src = "https://img.utdstc.com/icons/256/app-danger-check-android.png";
  }, false);
  imagen.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
      this.src = original;
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="http://requirementsinc.com/img/icon/PNG/danger.png" id="imagen">
</body>
```

Edit: Agregué también la variable original para regresar siemre la imagen original en el caso de que haya más imagenes y se decida usar otra propiedad para buscar los elementos en el DOM como la clase o el tag en lugar del ID.